# How do I fill rows with value from the previous row but with a limit?

Tags: r

If i have a row with a value followed by 10 NAs until the next value, how do i fill down to only the 5 rows after the value'd row, and not to the next row with a value?

Comment: What if you have 4 NAs after the value

Comment: Do you mean row or column?

Comment: I mean rows,  essentially, how do i use  fill(data, column, .direction = c("down")), but where it stops at a specified number of rows